# MoSKito 2.5.6 Inspect does not display annotated classes

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat7, java-8

I was using [the MoSKito integration guide](http://blog.anotheria.net/msk/the-complete-moskito-integration-guide-step-1/) to get moskito monitoring running for my maven+spring java-8 project. Everything works except that I cannot see my annotated services and controllers in MoSKito Inspect.

I tried the example project [burgershop](https://github.com/anotheria/burgershop) which comes with the tutorial (Tag: moskito-integration-guide-step1). Being unable to compile the project, i modified the pom.xml to use aspectj v1.7, moskito 2.5.6 and the moskito-inspect-remote artifact. With these modifications I am able to compile and connect moskito Inspect with the project. But I still cannot see the annotated controller and service classes as the tutorial describes. Is anybody able to help?

The Controllers are annotated with the @Monitor attribute.

(modifications of the pom.xml)

```
<properties>
    <moskito.version>2.5.6</moskito.version>
</properties>
...
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
        <artifactId>moskito-inspect-remote</artifactId>
        <version>${moskito.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
        <artifactId>moskito-core</artifactId>
        <version>${moskito.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
        <artifactId>moskito-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${moskito.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 ...
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.7</version>
         <configuration>
             <aspectLibraries>
                 <aspectLibrary>
                     <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
                     <artifactId>moskito-aop</artifactId>
                 </aspectLibrary>
             </aspectLibraries>
          <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
             <source>1.8</source>
             <target>1.8</target>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
             <execution>
                 <goals>
                     <goal>compile</goal>
                 </goals>
             </execution>
         </executions>
     </plugin>
     ...
```

Comment: Hi, 1) can you share your project (or enough code to test) on github or something? 2) do you actually access your producers through anything like ui? I mean do they actually do anything? 3) Have you checked the logs? You could see your producers in moskito logs being registered, something like this: 352 2015-03-25 19:33:55,643 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO   n.a.m.c.r.ProducerRegistryImpl:112 - Registry register producer: ThreadCount / BuiltInThreadCountProducer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try to use jdk 7 and example of my plugin part:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.level}</source>
                <target>${java.level}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
                        <artifactId>moskito-aop</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <complianceLevel>${java.level}</complianceLevel>
                <sourse>${java.level}</sourse>
                <target>${java.level}</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```